# How to connect to weather API using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, weather-api

I am trying to learn Requests and practicing by connecting to the weather API.  But for some reason I can't get it to work?  It is clear the weather API is wanting the param in a certain way that I cannot seem to figure out how it translates to Requests.

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', q={'Anderson'})
```

Here is the link to the API page:
https://openweathermap.org/current

I see the weather pages wants the param in terms of q = city, but the error I get is:

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'q'
```

Also here the the Requests page that I am referring to: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're giving the `request.get()` method an unexpected keyword argument `q`. It only accepts specific arguments, mentioned in the documentation

Comment: I know that, as I stated in my question.  My question is what is the correct keyword argument.

Comment: You require an openweather `appid` https://openweathermap.org/appid#get

Comment: Just got one, thanks for the info.  Waiting for it to authenticate then getting back to you on if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the `requests` user manual, at least the [quickstart guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart).
The RESTful API you are about to use expects GET request with `q="City Name"` parameter. Moreover you must have the [appid](https://openweathermap.org/appid) and add it for every request.

1. Register you application and choose a pricing plan https://openweathermap.org/price
2. Pass both `q="City Name"` and `APPID=xxx` parameters

Here is corresponding request:

```
api_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
appid = ...    
r = requests.get(url=api_url, params=dict(q='Anderson', APPID=appid))
```

Comment: This is running right, but it is not giving back the information.  It just finishes with 0 errors.  I though this was all I needed for the API to give me back the information or do I need more?

Comment: @RostSunshine Did you inspect the response object you got in return?  You may need to go through the manual as suggested.

Comment: The server responses with 401: Unauthorized. That means you should pass the authentication. Requests can do that http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Comment: I have and going through it again, I still was under the assumption that request.get() will send the params to the API link and that it will give back the information based on the parameter.  The only other method I see is .post() which doesn't appear to do what I want either.

Comment: Ah I am starting to see your point.  Didn't know authentication existed yet.

Comment: Yeah, you probably should buy kind of a license (appid) to use the API: https://openweathermap.org/appid#get

Comment: So I see I need the basic authorization.  But how does the auth = part tie into the params=dict(...) ?

Comment: The only problem I still have is that it just finishes and returns nothing.  I am assuming this means I need authentication.  How does this tie into the code.  Where do I put the auth =  This part is giving me errors as I move it around.

Comment: Never mind I am dumb I got it.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your call to the one that follows (by adding the api key to the `params`):

```
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', params={'q': 'Anderson', 'APPID': YOUR_API_KEY})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `appid` for openweather, which for individual use is free (https://openweathermap.org/appid#get)

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1')
>>> loc_weather = r.content.strip()
>>> loc_weather
'{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}'
```

Comment: what does the content.strip() do?

Comment: Just strips leading and trailing white space characters if there are any from `r.content`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for weatherbit.

**The url:**

```
url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/history/daily"
```

**Create a payload:**

```
payload = {'key':'12345fcfa0hjde13a7896fbdae1ghjkjh',
          'city_id': '1261481',  # This is New Delhi
          'start_date': '2021-03-13',
          'end_date': '2021-03-14'}
```

**Call it using GET** (the website specifies that GET call is supported):

```
data = requests.get(url, params=payload)
assert data.status_code == 200
assert 'error' not in data.json().keys()
```

Your data:

```
data.json() # Or text or content
```

My sys specs: Python 3.8, Request 2.25.1